# Finding the application support directory on OSX in java

Tags: java, macos

I would like to store some files in the application support directory is there some system call to retrieve this directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you will need to use something like this:

```
String applicationSupportDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support";
```

Comment: I've had to resort to this approach. I believe there is no way to retrieve the whole application support path directly.

Comment: According to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1170/_index.html this is the recommended way to do it.